# Is it possible to quantify electric power consumption on a fuse?

Tags: energy, fuses

If you have a common fuse, is there way quantify the power consumption which is flowing through this fuse, or could you replace the fuse with something that measures the power consumption but still works as a fuse?

If it is not possible, could you explain it is impossible?

Comment: Do you want to measure the energy used by something protected by a fuse or the energy lost in the fuse itself?

Comment: the energy used by something (not the fuse)

Comment: Then why did you accept the answer you did?

Comment: because I think it answered my question, if there is no resistance, the fuse itself can't measure the power. Of course the second answer is right as well, if you have resistance in series, you should be able to measure the power, as long as you know the resistance of the fuse (which should be close to zero). Wrong?

Comment: @Beffa I was just thinking that @David reply was a perfect reply to the question you did not ask. :)

Comment: @Beffa - Wrong.  There is significant, controlled resistance.  It's usually less than 1 $\Omega$ for a typical fuse, and *always* greater than zero (otherwise the fuse wouldn't blow).  You can measure the voltage across it to find the current delivered to your circuit, but as [endolith](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/12248/#12261) pointed out, it won't be constant wrt. temperature and thus to current.  You'd need a non-linear function (or lookup table...) to use a fuse as a current-sensing resistor; see my answer for more info.

Comment: O.K. I understand

Comment: You can measure current in a conductor inductively; it is not necessary to insert a current sensing resistor into the circuit. There are such devices: you just clamp the probe around a wire and get a readout.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A fuse is basically a resistor where resistance varies from almost zero to infinity.  So just like a resistor, measure the voltage drop across the fuse, and the current through it.  Calculate the Volts times Amps and you'll get Watts.  Since the resistance is almost zero, the voltage drop will also be almost zero.  And so the watts will be almost zero.  Not exactly zero, but close.

When the fuse is blown, the resistance is near infinity.  This will make the current basically zero.  And thus the watts will be basically zero.

The interesting part is when measuring the power while the fuse is blowing.  It's not impossible, but not easy either.  Basically you work out a system where you can graph the current and voltage on an o-scope then do some tricky math to work out the amount of energy required during the fuse-blowing event.  I've never done this, so I couldn't tell you what it looks like.

Comment: Fuses are actually rated by their I2T value; take a look at datasheets for fuses and you can see how long they'll take to clear a fault of 'X' Amps (among other things). OT for this question, but fusing is actually a fairly complex thing when you get beyond the normal board-level and household type of applications.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can count on the fuse's resistance to be stable or repeatable.  Put a small, but known, resistance in series with the fuse (0.1 Ω), and measure the voltage across it.  The voltage divided by the resistance will tell you the current. V / R = I

Maybe there are special components that act both as current-sensing resistors and as fuses, but I don't know of them.

Simultaneously, measure the voltage across the thing that's supplying this current (like the voltage from the fuse to your circuit's ground, if the fuse is on the high side).

Multiply current by voltage to get power.  P = V · I

Comment: OTOH if the fuse does not have repeatable resistance then how can it have repeatable resistance-dependent heating effects? I guess that the resistance may vary between models and manufacturers.

Comment: The resistance of the fuse will definitely change with temperature. At any particular current, its resistance will be repeatable, though.

Answer (score 3):

**The power consumption of the fuse itself:** \$P_{FUSE} = R_{FUSE} * I^2\$

The contribution of a fuse's power dissipation becomes significant when you count all the watts and milliwatts on the way to finding out about the efficiency of a device on the component level, e.g. in a switch-mode power supply. This is often done to cross-check the efficiency you measured on a black-box level (\$P_{OUT}\$ vs. \$P_{IN}\$).

**The power consumption of the device connected to the fuse:** Not measurable when just the two pins of the fuse are available. You can measure the current flowing to the circuit, but you don't know the exact voltage.

Answer (score 2):

@Zebonaut has a valid sidepoint. To correctly measure AC power you will need to capture both the current and the voltage waveforms (synchronized). This allows you to account for voltage variations and, more importantly, for the phase relationships between the current and the voltage.

This is especially important if you want to measure power usage of switch-mode power supplies (like phone chargers or computers) and motors (like the one in you blender or washing machine). You can on the other hand measure the power of resistive heaters (most electric heaters are resistive) using just the current without correcting for the voltage.

Answer (score 2):

Traditionally, to measure the power consumed by a circuit powered by a common input (which may be fused), a shunt resistor and shunt current monitor is used.

For an example, here's a diagram of TI's INA193:

[image: ti ina 193 diagram]

The basic functionality is that current across the shunt resistor \$R_S\$ creates a proportionally related voltage at the output.

These are available in three-pin and five-pin layouts; the three-pin devices (often SOT23-3) set an output current from \$V_{IN+}\$ to ground through a resistor attached to out (eliminating the ground and \$V+\$ nodes, but externalizing the \$R_L\$ resistor shown in the block diagram) or a five-pin device which creates a voltage somewhere between \$V+\$ and ground.

Obviously, you'd like to eliminate the \$R_S\$ component if possible, but there are three major disadvantages to this approach:

1. The voltage across the fuse may be wrong for your application.  Most shunt monitors are designed for voltages less than (and sometimes much less than) 500 mV.  The plain-Jane Bussman S500 glass tube series fuses have  voltage drops over 1V for currents less than 500 mA.  Higher current fuses will usually be able to use the power in the current to blow faster, and will therefore have voltage drops less than 200 mV, which is perfect for this application.
2. The resistance of the fuse will vary a lot.  For example, the 1A fuse in the S500 series has a cold resistance of 0.125 Ω, but a maximum voltage drop of 200 mV at 1 A.  \$V = I * R\$, so you'd expect the voltage drop to be 125 mV.  In fact, the fuse functions as a PTC/resettable fuse that goes out of control (but that's another topic), and almost doubles its resistance between the cold and rated current states.  I'm not sure (but I doubt) that this is a linear function, and it's also a function of the ambient temperature/cooling rate.
3. The direct connection of \$V_{IN+}\$ to the shunt monitor represents an unfused connection in your system.  This will be a very low current path; you can give it some protection with a very thin trace or a small resistor without affecting your signal much, but the former probably won't pass inspection and the latter defeats the purpose of using the fuse as the sensing element.  If you're using the fuse to protect equipment from damage (which might not be prudent - see [Designing with fuses...when to use?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/10643/designing-with-fuses-when-to-use)), you might be able to get away with it.  However, in general, you want a sharp disconnect of fused and unfused portions of your circuit.

You *could* do some calibration of your fuses, and come up with an equation to translate the input voltage to your current.  This would work best if you were primarily interested in the steady-state currents and the device was in an enclosure at a constant temperature.  However, you're only saving a few pennies apiece.

Comment: @Beffa - Was this the kind of answer you wanted?  The other answers are all very different....

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, was on holiday. I just wonder if it would be possible to replace the fuse with a power measure device (which of course would still work as a fuse). I found something (digitalstorm.org) which works somehow the way I expect and does even more. So, all answer helped me to understand, how I should do it, even if they're completely different. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Fuse resistance is dependant on temperature. In some case standards give (ENA 12.6 *The resistance of each rating of time fuse-link shall be measured at 60% of the melting time when carrying a direct current which causes melting in 0.2 seconds. The resistance values so measured shall not exceed the values given in Table 1.*
A more day to day approach is to measure the resistance (or divide volt by amp with a less than 25% rated current to avoid heating) in worst case the resistance will increase by a **factor 6 to 8 just before fuse blow** this can last for minutes, values found in literature & checked. This can be interesting to know how many watt to consider for an enclosure  for instance
example of "special" TLF fuse Table 1

| Time fuse-link rating(A) | Resistance ( ) |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 0.073 |
| 5 | 0.043 |
| 7.5 | 0.031 |
| 10 | 0.028 |
| 12.5 | 0.020 |
| 15 | 0.017 |

Comment: Very good .so at low volts fuses waste more power than mosfets

Answer (score 0):

See this project:
http://www.altmann.haan.de/riding_on_electrons/default.htm

He controls the motor torque by measuring the current through the fuse. In the most recent version it has changed to a shunt resistor, maybe because it seems difficult to guarantee the accuracy when the fuse varies its resistance with temperature changes...

Comment: Once a long time ago I pushed a vendor on the issue of fuse resistance tolerance because I wanted to use a fuse as a current sense resistor. Unfortunately I don't remember for sure what they said. But I think it was around 30%. And of course the resistance of the fuse will have a higher temperature coefficient than a normal current sense resistor.

Comment: We say **current goes through** a circuit element and **voltage drops across** the element.

Comment: @mkeith Yeah, also note that the deviation with temperature is not instantaneous and it is a positive coefficient, so I think it can be applied in a few cases.

---
Thanks Transistor.